# What framework for MVVM should I use in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I will develop new Universal Apps and I was wondering which MVVM framework will be better for me: Prism for Windows Runtime or maybe MVVM Light.

I have a little experience in WPF and in my opinion in this scenario Prism offer more. I'm developing also other Universal Apps and I'm using there MVVM light, but this project is simple and I use only binding, commands and ViewModelLocator.

My new project will be more advanced and I don't know what is the better way and what kind of benefits I can obtain.

I'm interested in this this Prism version: [enter link description here](http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I develop in WPF & learnt MVVM by writing my own simple framework. It really helped me grasp a solid understanding of the fundamentals required. Really to get started you only only need to write a base class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, an implementation of ICommand and decide whether to use View or ViewModel first principles.

I wrote a blog with tutorials which cover these issues:

[WPF Retraining at 30](https://wpffromscratch.wordpress.com/)

Comment: The last point about V vs VM first is the most controversial, IMO, and can have far reaching consequences.

Comment: Indeed. I have heard good things re MVVM Light, providing a base viewModel, commanding etc. Luckily I had the time to learn by writing these things myself in order to improve my understanding of the inner workings.

Comment: Do you have any expierience with Prism in Universal Apps ?

Comment: Had a play with Prism, looked at the bootstrapper etc. For MVVM light there's a great course on PluralSight: 'MVVM Light Toolkit Fundamentals'. It was written by Laurent Bugnion, the creator of MVVM light, Microsoft MVP & all round MVVM guru.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer caliburn micro, its a very good framework, i also wrote 2 blog posts about it a few months ago if you want to have a look:

[Part 1 - MVVM Basics using Caliburn Micro](http://christianjvella.com/wordpress/started-caliburn-micro-universal-apps-wp-winrt/)

[Part 2 - Navigation](http://christianjvella.com/wordpress/caliburn-micro-universal-apps-navigation-viewmodels-part-2/)

I am sure if you search you will find a lot of tutorials on this framework... and I really like it.